# using DDP in Node.js, how do you connect the client using a required simpler-config object?

Tags: meteor, ddp

I'm using simpler-config to pull in a config object from a file, at load time. When inspecting the code, I can see that the config object got instantiated correctly, however, my call to ddp.client(config.ddp) is failing with the config object. Putting the data back into the client call in the form of a local object continues to work

```
var ddpclient = new client({
  // All properties optional, defaults shown 
  autoReconnect : true,
  autoReconnectTimer : 500,
  maintainCollections : true,
  url: 'ws://blahblah.com/websocket'
});
```

Calling it as follows doesn't work:

```
var ddpclient = new client(config.ddp);
```

anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a config object like so (not something other than an object) that may contain values.

```
var config = {};
```

and you define the ddp part like so:

```
config.ddp = {
 // All properties optional, defaults shown 
  autoReconnect : true,
  autoReconnectTimer : 500,
  maintainCollections : true,
  url: 'ws://blahblah.com/websocket'
}

var ddpclient = new client(config.ddp);
```

If your code works then the above should work too:

Comment: That's what I thought too. In fact, I fell back to a hybrid approach, where I tried to just substitute the values from the config object in place of, for example, 500, from the example above. This failed as well. I came to suspect that DDP was exploiting some kind of artifact in the nature of an anonymous object. As it happens, in the same code segment, I'm successfully using an object from config to initialize mysql. I guess what I'm trying to say is, I'm pretty sure this is a DDP package problem, and I'm wondering if anyone has a workaround. Putting config data in your code doesn't scale wel

Comment: @ecarew I've worked on the DDP package it doesn't do this. It'll only set defaults you've not already set. See for yourself: https://github.com/oortcloud/node-ddp-client/blob/master/lib/ddp-client.js#L14-L21

Comment: An excellent example. The author of this coffee is using the method I was calling hybrid above. It also looks like the author was depending on a config file being brought into the app, but I didn't see an explicit call to include it. Well, since this isn't the first problem I've had with the metior stack, I'm wondering if it isn't time to open a ticket. After all, this should be no more difficult than seeing up my mysql connection.